# In the block scope even after initialisation with undefined var type of variable logs out unexpected value

Tags: javascript, hoisting

```js
function show() {
  var x = 10;
  if (true) {
    var x = 20;
  }
  console.log(x); // 20
}

show();
```

But when I not initialise the 'x' manually which is inside the 'if-statement', it initialise with **undefined** and hoisted to the top and should log the most recent value which is undefined , as 20 is logs out in the above example. But it logs out 10.Why?

```js
function show() {
  var x = 10;
  if (true) {
    var x;
  }
  console.log(x); // 10
}

show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`MDN - var:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#description)

> Duplicate variable declarations using var will not trigger an error,
> even in strict mode, and the variable will not lose its value, unless
> another assignment is performed.

So, unless you re-assign any value to `x`, variable declared with `var` will keep its value.

Re-declaring `x` inside the `if` block does not create a new variable; `x` is created only once.

From the [`Ecmascript spec - 14.3.2 Variable Statement:`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-variable-statement)

> A var statement declares variables that are scoped to the running
> execution context's VariableEnvironment. Var variables are created
> when their containing Environment Record is instantiated and are
> initialized to undefined when created. **Within the scope of any
> VariableEnvironment a common BindingIdentifier may appear in more than
> one VariableDeclaration but those declarations collectively define
> only one variable**.

That is why `x` in the following statement

```
var x;
```

doesn't implicitly gets initialized with `undefined`; this re-declaration statement didn't re-create the variable `x`.

```js
function show() {
  var x = 10;
  if (true) {
    var x = undefined; // re-assigned
  }
  console.log(x);
}

show();
```

---

**Note on hoisting:** Unless you know this already, variables are NOT literally hoisted/moved to the top of the scope in which they are declared; variable declarations are processed before the code execution, this is why they *appear* to have moved to the top of the scope.

For more details, see: [`MDN - var hoisting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: I think the inner 'x' gets initialised with undefined, even if you don't assign it explicitly. So, why my 2nd example logs out 10 instead of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are trying to relate above both example, you might confused. see both examples in different way, you will get the answer.